# Install kernlab package in R

Tags: r, failed-installation, suse

im trying to install kernlab package on a SLES 11 SP1. I installed all prerequisite packages eg. gcc-fortran...

After starting the installation with install.packages("kernlab") I get the following error messages. It would be great if anybody of you could help me out.

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib64 -o kernlab.so brweight.o ctable.o cweight.o dbreakpt.o dcauchy.o       dgpnrm.o dgpstep.o dprecond.o dprsrch.o dspcg.o dtron.o dtrpcg.o dtrqsol.o esa.o expdecayweight.o inductionsort.o kspectrumweight.o lcp.o misc.o msufsort.o solvebqp.o stringk.o stringkernel.o svm.o wkasailcp.o wmsufsort.o -L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.11.1/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/elf/start.S:109: undefined    reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [kernlab.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘kernlab’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/kernlab’

The downloaded source packages are in
   ‘/tmp/RtmpCf2yIn/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making packages.html  ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("kernlab") :
installation of package ‘kernlab’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Rstudio in Fedora 19.

Solve it by installing "Full R development environment metapackage" via the software package manager.

Comment: Will it solve the same problem for me, if I have R installed from sources? In my case I need a specific R version as it is recommended for SAP HANA database...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with opensuse for a bit.

I think it is to do with the path that you have installed gcc and fortran to (i.e., the problem is that R is not checking this path).

Have you installed gcc, etc using Yast?